# Different filename to class name yii

Tags: yii, yii2

In yii 2.0 for the class **is it possible** to use like below where Home is the name and Common is the folder

And then on the filename just have Home.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\common;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class HomeCommonController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex()
    {

        echo "From the Common Home";

    }

}
```

Then the url would be

```
http://localhost/yiitest/home
```

I am trying to see if possible to get same way opencart finds there controllers.

Comment: Why do you need such behavior? Every  framework has own agreements.

Comment: I just like it that way which is what open cart uses. So would like to know if could do it same way in yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible without overriding core classes. Yii2 do not perform search for folder names in controller class name. I do not recommend to go against framework standards and conventions. Each one has their own, better accept it and adapt to it.